# Kotlin: lag in coroutine runBlocking

Tags: android, kotlin, delay, coroutine

I am using kotlin Coroutines to perform async network operations to avoid `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.
The problem is the lag that happens when i use `runBlocking`,that take sometime to complete current thread.

How can i prevent this delay or lag,and allow the async operation to be done without delay

```
    runBlocking {
        val job = async (Dispatchers.IO) {
        try{
        //Network operations are here
        }catch(){

        }

     }

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `runBlocking` you are blocking the main thread until the coroutine finishes.

The `NetworkOnMainThread` exception is not thrown because technically the request is done on a background thread, but by making the main thread wait until the background thread is done, this is just as bad!

To fix this you could `launch` a coroutine, and any code that depends on the network request can be done inside the coroutine. This way code may still be executed on the main thread, but it never blocks.

```
// put this scope in your activity or fragment so you can cancel it in onDestroy()      
val scope = MainScope() 

// launch coroutine within scope
scope.launch(Dispachers.Main) {
    try {
        val result = withContext(Dispachters.IO) {
            // do blocking networking on IO thread
            ""
        }
        // now back on the main thread and we can use 'result'. But it never blocked!
    } catch(e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

---

If you don't care about the result and just want to run some code on a different thread, this can be simplified to:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        // code on io thread
    } catch(e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

Note: if you are using variables or methods from the enclosing class you should still use your own scope so it can be cancelled in time.

Comment: Thanks,but using the first solution,i can't return result to use it outside scope,how can i extract data outside scope to use it?(in my example,i use it to attach to ListAdapter)

Comment: You don't move it outside of the coroutine. Where it says '// now back on the main thread' you can access both the result and the outside scope. So there you could update your adapter or navigate for example

Comment: when i put in the same place as you mentioned:



val myListAdapter = InvestListAdapter(this,arg1,arg2,arg3)


it gives the following errors:
1-unresolved reference for arg1,arg2,arg3 (all these are inside scope)
2-this:type mismatch

Comment: You have variables called arg1, arg2 and arg3? and for the type mismatch: 'this' now points to a coroutine object, but you can use this@MainActivity or whatever class you where in to get that 'this' reference. Other that that your problem no longer has to do with coroutines so you may post a new question with your actual code